# Add another position to a contact or enable fullt-text search for position field

Tags: contacts, search

in CiviCRM running on WordPress I had to recognize that it creates problems when filling in two positions into the position field when adding a contact. The main problem is that you've got to type the exact name of the position when searching for a certain contact that's got that position. If this contact has got two positions, however, CiviCRM won't show that contact unless you search for both positions. Then, however, the search does not make any sense, since you would have to know all position of your contacts in advance...

Am I making a mistake here or is there a solution to that problem?

Thanks a lot for looking at this!
Best regards
Jannis

Edit: I am using the German translated version where the field 'position' is called 'Funktion'. So in an earlier version of this post it said 'function' instead of 'position'. Thanks a lot, @jitendrapurohit, for pointing at that problem! :)

Comment: What do you mean by the word `function` here? Is that a custom field?

Comment: It's a field where you can state the position of a person in a job, company or organisation. But maybe the term is different in English. I'm using the German version. In German the field name is 'Funktion', maybe in English it's 'Position'?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit thanks for pointing to that language problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholders for this.

- '%' for any number of characters
- '_' for exactly one character

Searching for '%CEO%' will find all contacts that have that substring somewhere in their position field.